# If I want ro check what PDOstmt->execute() returns, do i call it again in an if statment?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a basic insert query like so:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (row) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
```

Can I just call the execute in a if statement like this to check if the insert was succesfull?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (row) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
if ($stmt->execute()){echo "success"}
```

or do I have to call it first and then call it again in an if statement ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (row) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
$stmt->execute()
if ($stmt->execute()){echo "success"}
```

Comment: You would execute it twice with your second snippet. Your first one is correct.

Comment: why not try it and see what happens? But Qirel is right, the second one would make the query run twice....and you'd only test the success of the second attempt. The first sample is the way to do. Bear in mind that it's also possible for the prepare() and bindParam() methods to fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling $stmt->execute() twice will execute it twice.

It's better to use try and catch since prepare() and bindParam() may also fail:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (row) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Success';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```